# Grouping information by hour in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column that looks like this

```
0       01:41:21

1       01:41:42

2       01:41:56

3       01:58:41

4       07:34:08
```

How can I group other columns by hour

Comment: `df.groupby(df['column'].str[:2])`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.col_timestamp)
g = df.groupby(times.hour)
```